# I had similar questions on the internet that I have been trying for hours. But I couldn't handle it. I'd appreciate it if you helped

Tags: android

I had similar questions on the internet that I have been trying for hours. But I couldn't handle it. I'd appreciate it if you helped.

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class

```
2019-07-08 16:51:33.340 7478-7478/com.mobilprogramlar.girisanimasyonu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.mobilprogramlar.girisanimasyonu, PID: 7478 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mobilprogramlar.girisanimasyonu/com.mobilprogramlar.girisanimasyonu.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
```

... and ...

```
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.mobilprogramlar.girisanimasyonu.MainActivity.onCreate(**MainActivity.java:12**)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
Related lines in MainActivity;
```

enter preformatted text here

```
package com.mobilprogramlar.girisanimasyonu;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle; public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); } }
```

** activity_main content**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/giris_animasyon_renkleri"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You don't need to use `constraints` in a linear layout. Check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

Remove `constraints` attributes its used only when root element is `constraints layout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/giris_animasyon_renkleri"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</LinearLayout>
```